# React with Antd Component Modal Form with state issue

Tags: reactjs, forms, modal-dialog, state, antd

I can't figure out what is the right way to handle this -> I am beginner in React , so if this looks absurd, maybe I got this wrong.

I have a React component - which is a table/list with a list of Tasks

```
  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true,
    });
  };
.
render() {
return ( 
<Table />

        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
          Add New Task
        </Button>
<CRTaskForm
        visible={this.state.visible} />
```

I have another React component CRTaskForm - which is basically a Modal Form to add Tasks

Now, my issue is 
1. I want to handle the onSubmit in CRTaskForm - and close the form when the Task is created - there is a separate handler in CRTaskForm onSubmit(e) { .. } which handles sending the create task via REST to the server.

How do I close the Modal form in the onSubmit .. the "visible" props is not present in the CRTaskForm.

Comment: So, what I can think of, after reading some "more" posts, is something like this -> Parent - contains onShow function, and onHide function, onHide function is passed as a props to the child (actual modal component). The child Modal contains the onSubmit function which does some custom processing. Then the child Modal calls onHide when onsubmit processing is completed. Is that a right way of doing this? Is there some use-case I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function which closes the modal and pass it to the form as a prop:

```
closeModal = () => {
  this.setState({
   visible: false
})
}

...

<CRTaskForm visible={this.state.visible} closeModal={this.closeModal}/>
```

And just call it in your submit function.